# submit a form with AjaxToolkit?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

Can we submit a form in ASP.NET with AjaxToolkit ?

e.g:
below in our form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div id="mainDiv">
<table style="width: 40%;" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorUsername" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" 
            ValidationGroup="login"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        : UserName
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPass" 
            ValidationGroup="login"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        : Pass
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" 
            ValidationGroup="login"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelResult" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</form>
```

I wanna log-in a user with Ajax so I have to send username and pass to a `Webservice` and get the result and show the result in `LabelResult`.

Can we do it with `AjaxToolkit` in `ASP.Net`?

Comment: AJAX is built around the goal of a "partial postback" (or a callback) of some element "smaller" than (or in some cases 'other than') the whole form. If you want to submit the form, that is what a post back is for. Can you be more specific about why you want to use AJAX in this scenario?

Comment: I wanna login the user with Ajax just for learning, I know I can use `post back` but I wanna found the solution with Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, If we wanna send a form to server with Ajax, we have to use something like JQuery, and we can't do it with AjaxControlToolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ajax for a cascading dropdown menu set and i don't know how to submit the contents of the form to a controller. I think this is a related question becausewht I did was generate a hidden ajax control that triggered upon the change in value of the final ajax control in the form. The webservice that the control triggered then saved al of the form information to a database at which point the submitbuton was more of a comforting decoration for the user.  Once the user submitted the form the values were available in a meta data field in the database and the submit handler accessed those values rather than reading them from the postback.

I didthis because it ended up being faster than learning what I needed to in order to read them form the postback using java script or some other method of retrieval form the postback so I wouldn't claim thatthisis the best approach but it worked for me.  Hope this helpsyou somehow.

D.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

for working of AJAX **script manager must appear before the form** which i think not possible and also
 **Cos Callis** says very well
 "**If you want to submit the form, that is what a post back is for**"